# Git workflow npm dependencies versioning in Angular

Tags: angular, git, git-flow

In my project (Angular app) we aggregate several locally create artifacts published to npm repository.

In my app's package.json in the "dependencies" section I have:

```
    "@k/e-lib": "^0.3.0",
    "@k/et-lib": "^0.3.0",
    "@k/http-interceptors": "^0.3.0",
    "@k/notifications": "^0.3.0",
    "@k/static-assets": "^0.3.0",
    "@k/t-lib": "^0.3.0"
```

They are in-house components we develop in separate git repositories.

When we want to release project we release the master app with the components.

In order to release I create release branches from develop in all the repositories to freeze the code. Then I change the versions to, let's say, 0.4.0-0 for all. Next step would be to build and publish artifacts with the aforementioned version and update package.json in my master app.

How you handle this process, you simplify it or follow the steps above. Second question. After branching to release branch, do you change the current version in develop branch to something like 0.4.1 or you increment it to 0.3.1 and wait until release will be completed and merged back to develop.

Answer (score 0):

In git flow you only tag merges with the master branch with release numbers. Your develop branch does not know what version is currently released.

The idea of git flow is that your devs can work on their feature branch regardless if their feature makes the release. Only hot-fixes creates immediate release versions.

Here is an example flow of git using [gitflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow)

[image: git flow]

Comment: Thanks Jonas. I do that on the repository level but we have also certain correlation between source code and artifacts we produce basing on the source code revision. Do you suggest to version the npm artifacts independently from tags in git repo ? Currently when I am developing new feature and want to test it in the master app I create new artifact with bumped version, tag the commit in git then update this dependency in my master app. In that way we know when and how everything has been built.

Comment: It sounds like you have an extra step? eg. You are not confident that all master branch points should create npm artifacts. You could limit your releases to when the version hits a new 'upper' level. For example 1.0.1 wouldn't create a npm release, but when you hit 1.1 you would release your artifacts. So only bump the release to a major release when you are confident in your build.

Comment: In my case it's specific to npm, in order to see how everything interacts I need to combine all artifacts as dependencies. That induces new versions that are not part of any official release. I try to keep them versioned using Semantic Versioning rules. It works ok in daily development but it's not clear when we prepare for official release. Some solution would be to have separate versioning on dev/feature branches and official one on release/master.